# Convert decimal

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have for instance the following string: "0x780000105d0e0030"
If this is not the string, I can easily get the value as follows:

```
ulong myValue = 0x780000105d0e0030;
```

which give me the value of: 8646911354832027696
However, when I want to parse it as follows:

```
var myValue2= Convert.ToInt64("0x780000105d0e0030",16)
```

which give me the value of: 8070450566607667200

Then, then myValue is different than myValue2. myValue is correct however and this is how it should work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Int64` is a *signed* `long`.

Use [`Convert.ToUInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f0tesky.aspx) instead:

```
var myValue2= Convert.ToUInt64("0x780000105d0e0030",16);
```

Answer (score 3):

When `myValue` is unsigned Int64, `myValue2` is signed Int64.

What you actually need is `Convert.ToUInt64` function.

Comment: Now I only just woke up so I'm only 90% sure of this, but 7 is 0111 so the first bit is actually zero, so it should represent the same number as signed or unsigned.

Comment: Right but then how can the discrepancy be explained? Obviously the type is wrong, but the value should have been the same in this particular case..

Comment: The value is close to the upper bound of Int64.MaxValue. It could be the overflow problem due to the way Convert.ToInt64 is written.

Comment: Given how easy it is to write conversions without any overflow problem, something is very odd here.

Answer (score 2):

The value you are converting is within the range of Int64, and is converted to the equivalent Int64 value, as can be demonstrated by the following code:

```
ulong u = 0x780000105d0e0030;

Console.WriteLine("Convert.ToInt64(\"0x780000105d0e0030\", 16) => {0}", Convert.ToInt64("0x780000105d0e0030", 16));
Console.WriteLine("u                                         => {0}", u);
Console.WriteLine("u.ToString(\"x\")                           => {0}", u.ToString("x"));
Console.WriteLine("Convert.ToInt64(u.ToString(\"x\"), 16)      => {0}", Convert.ToInt64(u.ToString("x"), 16));
Console.WriteLine("u = (ulong)Convert.ToInt64(\"0x780000105d0e0030\", 16)");
u = (ulong)Convert.ToInt64("0x780000105d0e0030", 16);
Console.WriteLine("u                                         => {0}", u);
```

which results in the following output:

```
Convert.ToInt64("0x780000105d0e0030", 16) => 8646911354832027696
u                                         => 8646911354832027696
u.ToString("x")                           => 780000105d0e0030
Convert.ToInt64(u.ToString("x"), 16)      => 8646911354832027696
u = (ulong)Convert.ToInt64("0x780000105d0e0030", 16)
u                                         => 8646911354832027696
```

Which leaves two possibilities:

1. The version of .net you are using (I have 4.0.30319 RTMRel) has a major flaw in the implementation of Convert.ToInt64
2. You're passing in the string "0x7000000000000000" to the function instead.

My money would be on the latter explanation.